# Guesstimate time zone from time offset with JavaScript and Moment.js

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I know this is not going to be foolproof because an offset isn't specific to a timezone, but with location data it seems like it would be possible to make an educated guess.

Basically, I would like to be able to take an object similar to this:

```
{
  offset: -5,
  location: 'America'
}
```

...and get back either a single or multiple matching time zones, which would be:

```
['America/Montreal', 'America/New_York', ...]
```

One solution I can think of is iterating through the zone data provided by `moment-timezone`, but that just doesn't seem like an elegant way to get this info.

Any ideas?

Comment: aside: there are more than 24 timezones, e.g. +5:30 and +5:45, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets - not sure what you're doing with the `-5`, but you may also want to compensate for intermediate timezones as mentioned in previous.

Comment: Assuming you could do what you are asking, what would you do with the list of multiple time zones?  How would you narrow it down to one to use from there?  They could be quite different from each other.  Consider also that a single offset might be shared between two adjacent time zones near a DST transition.  For example, `2014-11-02T01:00-05:00` could be *either* US Central Daylight Time or US Eastern Standard Time  ([proof](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20141102T01&p1=64&p2=179)).

Comment: Like I said in the very first sentence, I'm very well aware of all this. An efficient way to make an educated guess is all I'm looking for.

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau Can you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moment-timezone@0.5.0` added [`moment.tz.guess()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/) which attempts to guess the user's most likely timezone by looking at `Date#getTimezoneOffset` and `Date#toString`. It then picks the zone with the largest population. It's not perfect, but it's close enough! Data is pulled from [this table](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/pull/220) and `Intl` is used when available.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvjxt7jr/11/)

```
moment.tz.guess()

//= America/New_York (I'm in America/Montreal, but this works too)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really elegant but iterating through the time zone database allows to get all timezones associated with a given offset.

Note that the timezone database stores the variation of offset due to the daylight saving rules and also the historical evolution of time zones.

Given an offset in minutes, this function returns, according to the [iana timezone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), the list of all timezones that used this offset once in the history or that will use this offset once in the futur.

```
function getZonesByOffset(offset){
  //offset in minutes
  results = [];
  var tzNames = moment.tz.names();
  for(var i in tzNames){
    var zone = moment.tz.zone(tzNames[i]);
    for(var j in zone.offsets){
      if(zone.offsets[j] === offset){
        //Add the new timezone only if not already present
        var inside = false;
        for(var k in results){
          if(results[k] === tzNames[i]){
            inside = true;
          }
        }
        if(!inside){
          results.push(tzNames[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```